# laravel scout not working with nWidart modules package

Tags: elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I use nWidart module package (https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/499) and Laravel scout for full text search.
Laravel scout import model with this command

```
php artisan scout:import "App\Product"
```

when model created in **App directory** everything is ok but when model created in nWidart package laravel scout show import correctly

```
Imported [\Modules\Product\Entities\Product] models up to ID: 304
All [\Modules\Product\Entities\Product] records have been imported.
```

but not insert in elastic database.

you can see all data with get method **http://localhost:9200/_search** in postman

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the module directory:

```
 php artisan scout:import "Modules\{module-name}\Entities\{entity-name}"
```

Worked for me.